# Factorising trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, factoring

In order to factorise $x^2-1$ one way of thinking about it would be to set it equal to zero and solve to get $x=1$ and $x=-1$.

You can then write $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$

Can we do the same with trigonmetric functions, i.e

sin$x=0 \implies x=n\pi$ so

sin$x=x(x-\pi)(x+\pi)(x-2\pi)(x+2\pi)...$

Comment: See [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good.  It is well known that the sine function can be written as

$$\sin \pi x =\pi x \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x^2/n^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

No. Try $x=\frac{1}{2}\pi$ and see that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Note that actually given the roots of a quadratic, you don't have a full specification. The same occurs with $\sin$ as well. Note that $\sin(x)$ and $2\sin(x)$ have the same roots for example. Also you must be *very* careful with infinite products such as the one you just wrote down.

Comment: So when can I do this kind of things and where I cannot ? What rules should I follow in order to treat infinite sum as infinite products and viceversa ?

Comment: @RenatoFaraone It's unclear to me what you mean by "treating a sum as a product". Infinite products in general only make sense if the number of factors $>1$ is finite for any input. In your example for $\sin x$, this is not the case. Also your products will most likely be preceeded by a scalar factor. For example $2x^2 - 4x + 2 = 2(x-1)^2$ where $1$ is a double root and $2$ is that factor.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that ratio of both sides is a bounded function. Since that ratio only has removable singularities, it is a complex analytic function, the boundedness then implies by [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) that the ratio is actually a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. The product you are suggesting does not converge except at point $x=n\pi$. But a variant does work.

The function $\sin(\pi z)$ can be expressed as the **infinite product**
$$\pi z\prod_1^\infty \left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2}\right).$$
From this you can get an infinite product representation for $\sin x$ by setting $z=\frac{x}{\pi}$.

This result is due to Euler, and played a crucial part in his famous  proof of the fact that $1+\frac{1}{ 2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\cdots =\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.